# Laravel - populate array w/ default values | POST method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Q&A:
I would like to set some default values to avoid empty fields.

- I want to set the default values in the **Controller** not the html
- Forms placeholders don't work as filled field
- I want to still be able to outputs the error if some of the key value is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found just the right way to acomplish this by using array merge:

```
array_merge($requested, $default)
```

- The keys from the first array will be preserved! You should check [php](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) doc.
- Then proceed (**create** & **redirect**).
- Unspecified keys will throw errors, also you should check `'strict' => false` in the `config/database.php` if you run into a problem.

**{NameController.php}**

```
$default = array(['image' => 'http://placehold.it/250x225']);
$request = request(['user' => request('user')]);

$input = array_merge($request, $default);

{Model}::create($input);

return redirect('{view}');
```

---

- BE AWARE that this method leads to **MassAssigmentExeption** if you didn't set the $guarder or $protected fields in the {Model}.

---

*I am new to stack so please tell me if something is wrong, thx.*

Comment: what if you use something like `$requests = request()->all(); $requests['user'] = request()->user ? request()->user : 'http://placehold.it/250x225';` //just a suggestion though so you don't need `array_merge`

Comment: Nice, this is even better.

Comment: You also can use PHP 7 Null coalescing operator
`$requests['user'] = request()->user ?? 'http://placehold.it/250x225';`